# Problem with expo, util couldnt be found within the project

Tags: reactjs, expo, native

[Error output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPhpJ.png)

got error and couldnt get it fixed idk whats problem last thing i remember was installing latest version of npm, after that rolled back and installed everything with old package.json but cant get this fixed. this is my package.json

```
    {
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@brainsbeards/react-native-animated-code-input": "^1.0.1",
    "@expo-google-fonts/inter": "^0.2.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "~1.15.0",
    "@react-native-community/slider": "^3.0.3",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.0.1",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.1",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.0.1",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "expo": "~42.0.1",
    "expo-app-loading": "^1.1.2",
    "expo-av": "^9.2.3",
    "expo-blur": "^9.0.3",
    "expo-clipboard": "^1.1.0",
    "expo-font": "~9.2.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.4",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-42.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-easy-grid": "^0.2.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",
    "react-native-render-html": "^6.0.5",
    "react-native-toast-message": "^1.4.9",
    "react-native-web": "^0.17.1",
    "react-native-webview": "^11.6.6",
    "react-query": "^3.19.2",
    "zustand": "^3.5.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.9.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: suggestion: You can format the code with code fences to make it better to read

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue. Was able to remedy my situation but installing the util package.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/util